# How am i able to connect to mysql without entering any username or password?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php.
I am learning in Ubuntu Operating system.

I tried connecting to mysql, but I made a mistake i forgot to enter username and password but still I was able to connect. How is that ??

My Code :

```
<?php

    mysql_connect('localhost','','') or die('Could not connect to database');

    echo "Connected to database";

    ?>
```

output :

[image: Screen shot of my output]

Comment: You can connect to the database server without a username/password.... but you can't do much once you're connected - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connecting.html

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: @MarkBaker you have some more resources on this? I'm not able to find more information on this default `odbc` user you connect with default if you leave the username empty.

Comment: What more resources do you want beyond the MySQL manual? It's as close to the horses mouth as you can get

Comment: Without a username/password you're connecting to the MySQL __server__, not to a __database__

Comment: What is this account used for? The manual does not specify any permissions/reasons for the account being there on first sight

Answer (score 1):

Before someone starts flaming you for using mysql_connect, i would suggest you to always check the manual for functions. ( Here you can find some infos about your function http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php and you see it's deprecated. use at least mysqli.).

Another great resource is http://www.phptherightway.com/#mysql_extension

The answer above is correct (you're passing an empty string) but looking in the manual, you'll see that even without passing anything you should be able to connect ("Default value is defined by mysql.default_user" if sql_safe_mode is off, in your php.ini).

i imagine the fault is not yours for using mysql_connect, but of some old tutorial still around!

Keep up and cheers!